# Rails: Routing and form for custom controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm getting this error attempting to create a page that shows room details. Pressing on edit will triggger a popup window with prefilled values of the room clicked. And clicking save on the window will update data for that entry.

I'm not so sure how to predefine the id, I'm currently using jQuery to populate the form with current data of selected records.

```
No route matches {:action=>"save_details", :controller=>"rooms"}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

rooms/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@room, url: save_details_room_path) do |f| %>
        <% f.text_field :id, id:'edit-room-id', class:'d-none' %>
        <% f.text_field :name, id:'edit-room-name' %>
        <% f.text_area :desc, id:'edit-room-desc', style:'width: 90%; height: 8em; resize: none; float: bottom' %>

        <%= f.submit 'Save', :class=>'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
```

rooms_controller.rb

```
def save_details
    logger.info ('Hello world')
    @room= Room.find(params[:id])
    @room.name = params[:name]
    @room.description = params[:desc]

    @room.save
    redirect_to rooms_url
end

def show
    @room = Room.find(prams[:id])
end

def index
    @room = Room.all
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :rooms do
    get :save_details, on: :member
end
```

main.js

```
    const name = $(this).data('name');
    const desc = $(this).data('description');
    const id = $(this).data('id');

    $('#edit-room-id').val(id);
    $('#edit-room-name').val(name);
    $('#edit-room-desc').val(desc);
```

1ST EDIT:

Now I'm doing this another way which is just to simply pass the form as a url through, eg. /rooms/save_details?id=1,name=123,desc=1234. However the form just simply routes it into the default show/index methods in my controller. Anyway to route it directly to save_details method? Doing the below simply returns the error that says save_details does not exist as an id. Also editted my routes

new routes.rb

```
    get     '/rooms/save_details/:id/:name/:desc' => 'rooms#save_details', :as => 'save_details'
```

index.html.erb

```
<form action="rooms/save_details" method="get">
    ....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to save a form, this probably shouldn't be a `get`

```
resources :rooms do
    post :save_details, on: :member
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `:id` parameter on your route helper. You need to do:

```
<%= form_for(@room, url: save_details_room_path(id: @room.id)) do |f| %>
```

And as Asthmatic suggested, that will have to be a `:post` route if a form is being submitted to it.

It appears you're using jQuery to fill in the room id, so you may have to skip the Rails form helper in favor of a plain HTML form. In that case you'll have to build and add the `action` attribute after you have the room id.

Comment: How else can I fill the id with rails though? I get this error after adding the id field though. 

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Yep, that's because `@room` is `nil`. If `@room` is a new record it won't have an id.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by using a normal HTML form and adding the following in routes.rb

```
get '/rooms/save_details/:id/:name/:desc' => 'rooms#save_details', :as => 'save_details'

resources :rooms do
    get 'save_details', on: :collection
end
```